# Is there a way to pull specific child class from a parent class object variable?

Tags: c#, object, oop, inheritance, parent-child

I have a Room class which holds a Mob object. A Mob object can either be of type Passive or of type Hostile and each have their own specific behavior. These Mob objects will move around from Room to Room. If a Player tries to fight one of them, I need a way to call the specific behavior of the Mob's actual type. As in, Passive will try to evade while Hostile will try to fight back. Is there a way to do this without casting?

```
public class Room {
    private Mob mob;
    public Mob Mob { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Mob {
    protected Room room;
}

public class Passive : Mob {
    // Some passive-specific code
    public void Run() { }
    public void SayGreeting() { }
    public void SayGoodbye() { }
}

public class Hostile : Mob {
    // Some hostile-specific code
    public void Fight() { }
    public void SayOnLose() { }
    public void SayOnWin() { }
}
```

I know (Passive)myRoom.Mob and (Hostile)myRoom.Mob can do the trick but I'm wondering if there is a better option. Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't want to do it like that. Consider implementing strategies and calling a common method.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils You are probably correct. But I'm not sure I could implement strategy design pattern because the two mob types don't necessarily share a common method. I added additional information to my problem to help show this.

Comment: You can't access members specific to a derived type without casting as that type. If you want to be able to access a member via a reference of the base type then it needs to be a member of the base type. That's it, that's all. You need to find a way to make those members of the base type, as I demonstrated for `Run` and `Fight`, or else you will need to cast. If nothing else, you always have the option of leaving a method empty for one derived type or the other.

Comment: There's also the option of not using derived types at all. You could just use a single `Mob` class with all the functionality and an `IsHostile` property of type `bool`. That would also enable you to switch a `Mob` from one state to the other, which could be useful.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That's what I figured. I started with leaving a method empty but I was just wondering if there was a better way. I like your idea of switching the state but I don't necessarily want to be limited to two Mob types so I probably wouldn't use a bool in my case. Thank you for your time and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of inheritance and polymorphism. One option would be declare a method for the default action in the base class, then override that and implement it appropriately in each base class, e.g.

```cs
public abstract class Mob
{
    protected Room room;

    public abstract void PerformDefaultAction();
}

public class Passive : Mob
{
    // Some passive-specific code
    public void Run() { }

    public override void PerformDefaultAction()
    {
        Run();
    }
}

public class Hostile : Mob
{
    // Some hostile-specific code
    public void Fight() { }

    public override void PerformDefaultAction()
    {
        Fight();
    }
}
```

Now you can just call `PerformDefaultAction` on each `Mob` reference and it will behave appropriately based on its run-time type without you having to know what that is.

You don't even necessarily need the `Run` and `Fight` methods any more, as you can just put the type-specific code in the `PerformDefaultAction` method. There may be a reason that you want to keep them though.

Comment: I added additional information to my problem. While I could use this for the different fight responses, do you know if there is a way to call Mob-specific situational responses? Like if I want to greet a Passive mob (and the Hostile mob does not have that functionality).

Comment: @CreativeGuy888, I've shown you how to access type-specific functionality through a reference of the base type. If you aren't able to add a member to the base type then you can't access that functionality via the base type, so you have no choice but to cast. You can do conditional casts if necessary, but you still need to cast as a particular type to access members specific to that type.